# MVCContrib ActionFilter PassParametersDuringRedirect still passes reference type in querystring

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvccontrib

I am attempting to use the PRG pattern in an asp.net mvc 2 rc application.

I found that the MVCContrib project has a custom action filter that will auto persist the parameters in TempData

In an action I have the following

```
return this.RedirectToAction(c => c.Requested(accountAnalysis));
```

however this is adding a querystring param to the request e.g

`http://mysite.com/account/add?model=MyProject.Models.AccountAnalysisViewModel`

Can anyone explain how I can use the PassParametersDuringRedirect filter attribute from MVCContrib to not pass the ViewModel type in the querystring.

I see a [patch](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/WorkItem/View.aspx?WorkItemId=4405) was issued to fix this however in the latest MvcContrib that supports MVC 2 RC it is commented out as follows

```
public static RedirectToRouteResult RedirectToAction<T>(this Controller controller, Expression<Action<T>> action)
            where T : Controller
        {
            /*var body = action.Body as MethodCallExpression;
            AddParameterValuesFromExpressionToTempData(controller, body);
            var routeValues = Microsoft.Web.Mvc.Internal.ExpressionHelper.GetRouteValuesFromExpression(action);
            RemoveReferenceTypesFromRouteValues(routeValues);
            return new RedirectToRouteResult(routeValues);*/
            return new RedirectToRouteResult<T>(action);
        }
```

Any help much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed after a chat with Jeremy Skinner.

http://github.com/mvccontrib/MvcContrib/commit/135411386b6817def9aaa493493ff582788ba377

Comment: Where can I download the latest MvcContrib dlls?

Comment: Can you give me working dll's please? 
serhiy.shekhovtsov@gmail.com

Comment: get the latest git and build it

Comment: I just didn't want to sort git out. I thought there is shared build of last version.